# disnake discord бот непонятная ошибка

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api, disnake

вот мой код бота
intents = disnake.Intents.all()

```
intents = disnake.Intents.all()
```

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot {bot.user} is ready to work!")

@bot.event

async def on_member_join (member):
    channel = bot.get_channel ( 1168180239076180030 )

    role = disnake.utils.get (member.guild.roles, id=1168187960479469568)
    print ('user join the servers')
    await member.add_roles( role )
    await channel.send( embed = disnake.Embed( description = f'``{member.name}`` присоиединился', color = 0x0c0c0c))'
```

но постоянно выходит ошибка как вы видите intents стоят и в самом дискорд апи на сайте в боте тоже роль в дискорде тоже проставленна администратора но все равно такая ошибка я уже не знаю что делать

```
user join the servers
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\damn\Desktop\whister\venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\damn\Desktop\whister\main.py", line 40, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles( role )
  File "C:\Users\damn\Desktop\whister\venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\member.py", line 1034, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\damn\Desktop\whister\venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\http.py", line 409, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
disnake.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: Как минимум, отключить т9, когда задаете вопросы на сайте. Две строки можно грамотно и быстро набрать вручную.

Comment: спасибо бро помогло очень))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Бот не может выдавать роли, которые находятся выше его самой высокой роли. В списке ролей в настройках сервера поднимите роль бота выше в списке, и всё будет хорошо работать. 
Прежде чем браться за написание ботов, изучите механики работы Дискорда. Это не издевательство, а дружеский совет

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит сама за себя. У бота не хватает достаточно прав для того, чтобы изменить/добавить роли человеку. Попробуйте поднять права бота, или поставить его роль выше, чем роль, которую вы хотите выдать. Так-же, как и zrx, советую вам подучить уровень английского, чтобы понять ошибки, а также механики Discord-а.